# Is there a way to remove the "Delete note" function?

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce order notes there is a link to delete order notes. Is there a way to remove this ability to remove that ability?

Comment: You could just hide it with CSS - would this be enough?

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your comment, I think that would, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_delete_note_from_edit_order');
function hide_delete_note_from_edit_order()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->post_type === "shop_order" && $screen->base === "post") {
        echo '<style>a.delete_note { display:none; }</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you so much Mark i'll try that.

Comment: @RonHenderson cool let me know how you get on, and don't forget to mark it as accepted if it works for you ;)

Comment: Thank you! This worked really great for me.